# Why do I have to create a separate task to run a process here?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winapi

I have a console application which tries to create a process this way:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string path = @"C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe";
    const string param = "";

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                          {
                              Process pp = CreateProcessAsUser(path, param);
                              pp.WaitForExit();
                          }, 
                          TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If I run it CSRSS.exe shows a window with an error message: "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142)". If I change this to the following code everything works fine:

```
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                         {
                             Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                                               {
                                                                   Process pp = CreateProcessAsUser(path, param);
                                                                   pp.WaitForExit();
                                                               });
                              task.Wait();
                          }, 
                          TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent | TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

Do you have any ideas why?

Here is the code for CreateProcessAsUser:

```
public static Process CreateProcessAsUser(string filename, string args)
{
    IntPtr hToken = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token;
    IntPtr hDupedToken = IntPtr.Zero;

    ProcessInformation pi = new ProcessInformation();
    SecurityAttributes sa = new SecurityAttributes();
    sa.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

    DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, 
                     genericAllAccess, 
                     ref sa, 
                     (int)SecurityImpersonationLevel.SecurityIdentification, 
                     (int)TokenType.TokenPrimary, 
                     ref hDupedToken);

    STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
    si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
    si.lpDesktop = string.Empty;

    string path = Path.GetFullPath(filename);

    using (WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        CreateProcessAsUser(hDupedToken, 
                            path, 
                            string.Format("\"{0}\" {1}", filename.Replace("\"", "\"\""), args), 
                            ref sa, 
                            ref sa, 
                            false, 
                            0, 
                            IntPtr.Zero, 
                            @".\", 
                            ref si, 
                            ref pi);
    }

    return Process.GetProcessById(pi.dwProcessID);
}

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateProcessAsUser", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(...)
```

Comment: TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent needs a parent Task to attach to.

Comment: @usr if you read this you would find answers to all your questions. Application works without any exceptions, but in described case the system can not start the process and tells about it via error message window from CSRSS.exe. Unfortunately, I can not make this post shorter.

Answer (score 1):

I slapped [***this***](http://pastebin.com/jPARa0tp) together to try and reproduce your error but it works fine with both calls.